# Semantic error using if/else to make abecedarian series

Tags: python, for-loop, traversal, if-statement

My program is supposed to output:
Jack, Kack, Lack, Mack, Nack, Ouack, Pack, and Quack.

```
suffix="ack"
prefix="JKLMNOPQ"

for i in prefix:
    if prefix=="Q" or "O":
        suffix="uack"
    else:
        suffix="ack"
    print i + suffix
```

But instead it outputs
Juack, Kuack, Luack, Muack Nuack
Ouack
Puack
Quack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are comparing `prefix` (a string containing several letters) - instead of the current character, `i` - to single letters. They are never equal. I'd suggest better names (which would make the error obvious): `prefixes = "JK..."` and `for prefix in prefixes:`.
2. You are coercing `"O"` to a boolean by using it, without any comparision operator, in a logical or. If `prefix=="Q"` is false, it converts `"O"` to a boolean - and non-empty strings are considered true. Either use `prefix == "Q" or prefix == "O"` or `prefix in ("Q", "O")` (which scales better for more alternatives). You wouldn't believe how common this error is... yeah, it happens to use a few keywords borrowed from english, but it's not english </rant>

Comment: @tom10: Works as well. It's less general though (only for single characters).

Answer (score 1):

You should be comparing against `i` instead of `prefix` in the loop.  The `if prefix == 'Q' or 'O'` would always be `True` even if you were comparing against `i` since `'O'` is not `False`.  This should be `if i == 'Q' or i == 'O'`.

Comment: `prefix` is `"JKLMNOPQ"`. It will never be equal to `'Q'` or `'O'`

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: you are correct in that `prefix` would never equal `Q` or `O` but `bool(prefix=='Q' or 'O')` will result in `True` regardless of the value that `prefix` is bound to.

Comment: True but you explicity asked him in your answer to use `if prefix == 'Q' or prefix == 'O'` which is wrong.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: I made the stupid mistake of assuming that `prefix` was already referring to a single character - my brain did the substitution of `i` for `prefix` without me noticing ... d'oh.

Comment: That's another issue with the original code. The variable names are not well chosen.

Answer (score 1):

`prefix == "Q" or "O"` is completely wrong.

1. prefix will always be `"JKLMNOPQ"` and so will never be equal to `"Q"`. I think you meant to check for `i` rather than `prefix`
2. The `==` binds closer than `or` so it will evaluate to `(prefix == "Q") or "O"`. `"O"` is always true so suffix will alwasy be "uack"`

If you fix these, it should work.

I think it should be `if i=="Q" or i=="O"`.

Comment: `O` has got nothing to do with this. `or` short circuits. `O` won't even be evaluated, since `Q` returns `True`. `O` only evaluates if `Q` returns `False.`

Comment: @A A: No, operator precedence is chosen sensibly in Python so you can write `expr cmp-op expr logical-op expr cmp-op expr` without parens. It will evaluate the `==` first.

Comment: You're wrong A A. The code never tests the boolean value of `Q`. It tests the boolean value of `prefix == "Q"` which will always be `False`. Therefore, the `or` has not short circuited. It will then evaluate `"O"` which will return `True`. Try evaluating `p = "abc" ; p == "Q" or 1`. It will evaluate to `1`.